# Storing ASP.NET style security in SQL Server xml column?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I would like to store security information for records in a SQL Server database.  The security info would ideally be in the same form as what you might see in a config file, for consistency purposes:

```
<authorization>
     <allow roles="Admins"/>
     <allow users="SomeGuy,SomeOtherGuy"/>
     <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

I'd then like to be able to query the database for everything that a particular user is permitted access to, given their username and a list of their roles.

**Does anyone have a suggestion on how best to do this?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?**

An easy brute force solution would be to just read every row in the database and pull each security rule XML into some class that will do the evaluation for me - but obviously that's going to be slow and on large tables will be unreasonable.

Another thing that comes to mind is making a child table of some kind which includes a priority of some kind to indicate the order in which each allow or deny node should be applied.  However, I have quite a few tables that need this feature, and if I can avoid creating a ton of child tables, that would be ideal.

Though I have limited experience with XML columns in SQL Server, I can probably build an XML query to determine if a user is allowed - something starting with `(/authorization/allow/@users)[1]`, perhaps.  However, the order of the nodes matters, so while I could probably find a node that matches a given name or role, I don't know how to do any sort of set-based operation to check whether the user is denied or allowed based on which comes first.

**So, given a user name and a comma delimited list of roles, what is the best way to check that person's access rights on a particular row in the database?**

Comment: Are you trying implement some sort of roll your own row level security based on roles?

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm trying to do.  I want admins to be able to dynamically control access to various records in any table by simply adding an XML column of a pre-specified name and pushing the security rules into that column.

Comment: Creating row level security like that is a BIG piece of work. You might get lucky and find somebody who has done that but this is a much bigger topic than an online forum is well suited for.

Comment: I understand that it's a big piece of work - but i'm only asking a relatively straightforward question (unless someone wanted to tell me specifically that i was going about it the wrong way).  I have a defined XML structure that i'd like to query.  I have access to a comma delimited list of roles.  I want to evaluate the XML with a set-based operation, rather than cycling every single row and doing it with C# code.  I'm confident i can make it work, but i was hoping that someone with more MSSQL XML experience could suggest a specific query.

Comment: I should mention that i've implemented row based security in an application before, but it was all programatically controlled in the app, and wasn't quite this flexible.  So like i said in the previous comment - i'm confident i can make it work, but i'm hoping to end up with something a bit more flexible and with a bit better performance.

Comment: You can override the role provider and handle this in the application layer a lot easier than putting it in database in XML.  It seems like you're going about it the wrong way, but you haven't given us enough information for us to determine that -- it'd take your level of knowledge with your business/system constraints to know that for sure. It would be helpful to know *why* you think you need row level security; as that would guide any potential solution.

Comment: One example is a list of various kinds of content in the system.  There are reports, forms, charts, and other content - some clients will have literally thousands of different content items.  Admins should be able to intimately control which users have access to which items.  So they would set security on each item (or groups of items).  When a regular user searches for a particular keyword, the system could then list out all of the different reports and what not that they have access to which match the keyword.  I could grab the records and then parse security, but paging becomes cumbersome.

Comment: This is just one example, though.  I'd like this kind of functionality to be generically available for lots of other pieces - basically for any table in the database.  What i have is functional now, just not great for big tables.  But as i said in my answer to my own question, initially i don't have anything over 10k rows which needs this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i've come up with a solution, but it's not ideal.  For 10,000 records, it takes 5 seconds to return all of the rows which match the security profile.  This isn't a total disaster, and it does work, but i'll have to come back to this problem later to improve it.

Here's how i solved it.  Keep in mind that i only worked on this for a few hours.

Before i could really do anything, i knew i was going to need a function to compare two comma delimited lists.  I need to have a user's roles in a list, and see if any of those roles appear in the authorization settings stored in my xml column, as detailed in the original post.  For this, i made two functions.

The first function is a commonly seen one to do string splitting using xml:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'ufnSplitStrings') 
    AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')
)
    DROP FUNCTION ufnSplitStrings
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnSplitStrings
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

With that function established, i could then create another function which would then do the comparison i wanted:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'ufnContainsAny') 
    AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')
)
    DROP FUNCTION ufnContainsAny
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnContainsAny(@List1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @List2 NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS int 
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Ret AS INT = 0

    SELECT @Ret = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ufnSplitStrings(@List1, ',') x
    JOIN dbo.ufnSplitStrings(@List2, ',') y ON x.Item = y.Item

    RETURN @Ret
END;
GO
```

Finally, i could use that function to assemble my main UserIsAuthorized function.

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'ufnUserIsAuthorized') 
    AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')
)
    DROP FUNCTION ufnUserIsAuthorized
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnUserIsAuthorized(@SecurityRules XML, @UserName NVARCHAR(64), @UserRoles NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS int 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret int = 0;
    DECLARE @AuthType NVARCHAR(32);


    DECLARE @authRules Table (a nvarchar(32), u nvarchar(max), r nvarchar(max), o int)

    INSERT INTO @authRules
    SELECT
        a = value.value('local-name(.[1])', 'varchar(32)'),
        u = ',' + value.value('@users', 'varchar(max)') + ',',
        r = ',' + value.value('@roles', 'varchar(max)') + ',',
        o = value.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int')
    FROM @SecurityRules.nodes('//allow,//deny') AS T(value)

    SELECT TOP 1 @AuthType = a FROM @authRules
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + @UserName + ',', u) > 0 OR CHARINDEX(',*,', u) > 0 OR dbo.ufnContainsAny(r, @UserRoles) > 0 OR CHARINDEX(',*,', r) > 0
    GROUP BY a
    ORDER BY MIN(o)

    IF (@AuthType IS NOT NULL AND @AuthType = 'allow')
        SET @ret = 1;

    RETURN @ret;
END;
```

That function splits up the xml allow and deny nodes into a table which contains the authorization type (allow or deny), the users list, the roles list, and finally the order in which the particular node appears in the document.  Finally, i can grab the first node where i find the user or one of the user's roles.  If that node is "allow", then i return a 1.

Yeah, it's a bit horrendous because we're declaring a table in every single call.  I tried various little tests where i only looked for the user name (to avoid having to make any calls to the ufnContainsAny), but the performance didn't change.  I also tried changing the "o" column to a simple identity column, since i'm selecting all nodes - this would allow it to skip what i thought might be a time consuming calc of getting the order of the node.  But that also didn't affect the performance.

So, not surprisingly this method needs work.  If anyone has any suggestions, i'm all ears.

My initial usage of this feature will be very few rows, so i can use this in the interim until i come up with a better solution (or abandon this method altogether).

**EDIT:**

The performance can be dramatically improved by just skipping the DECLARE table / INSERT.  Instead, we can do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @AuthType = a FROM 
(
SELECT
    a = value.value('local-name(.[1])', 'varchar(32)'),
    u = ',' + value.value('@users', 'varchar(max)') + ',',
    r = ',' + value.value('@roles', 'varchar(max)') + ',',
    o = value.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int')
FROM @SecurityRules.nodes('//allow,//deny') AS T(value)
) AS sec
WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + @UserName + ',', u) > 0 OR CHARINDEX(',*,', u) > 0 OR dbo.ufnContainsAny(r, @UserRoles) > 0 OR CHARINDEX(',*,', r) > 0
GROUP BY a
ORDER BY MIN(o)
```